# Laravel no guarda la foto

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas gracias por la ayuda,

bueno, tengo una opcion para subir fotos, pero no hace nada, solo refresca, anteriormente hice un var dump de la variable que trae y si que envia el formulario, pero cuando añado el resto del codigo no hace nada. Ni da error ni nada, se queda en el sitio, y no hace nada.

gracias

**Imagecontroller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use App\image;


class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() //para restrigingir acceso para usuarios no logeados
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function create(){
        return view('image.create');
    }
    public function save(Request $request){
      //Validación
        $validate = $this->validate($request, [
            'description' => 'required',
            'image_path'  => 'required|image'
        ]);
        
        // Recoger datos
        $image_path = $request->file('image_path');
        $description = $request->input('description');
        
        // Asignar valores nuevo objeto
        $user = \Auth::user();
        $image = new Image();
        $image->user_id = $user->id;
        $image->description = $description;
        
        // Subir fichero
        if($image_path){
            $image_path_name = time().$image_path->getClientOriginalName();
            Storage::disk('images')->put($image_path_name, File::get($image_path));
            $image->image_path = $image_path_name;
        }
        
        $image->save();
        
        return redirect()->route('image.create')->with([
            'message' => 'La foto ha sido subida correctamente!!'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**createblade.php**

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{ Route ('image.save') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf

        <div class="form-group row">
            
            <label for="Image_path" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Imagen</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                
                <input id="Image_path" type="file" name="Image_path" class="form-control" required="" />  

                @if($errors->has('image_path'))
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('image_path')}}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            
            <label for="descripcion" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Descripción</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                
                <textarea id="descripcion" type="text" name="descripcion" class="form-control" required=""> </textarea>   
                @if($errors->has('description'))
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('description')}}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
               
             <input type="Submit" name="" class="btn btn-primary" value="subir imagen" />
  

@endsection
```

**routes:**

```
Route::get('/subir-imagen','ImageController@create')->name('image.create');
Route::post('/image/save', 'ImageController@save')->name('image.save');
```

que puede ser? no encuentro el error por ningun lado

+Nuevos errores de cogido, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto url del controlador de imagen:

snipper.io/s/-MIIX4aFUatC-deiF7Yp

gracias por la gran ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero es hacer el llamado a las dependencia:

```
use Str;
use Image;
use Storage;
```

De esta forma es igual que hacerlo de la siguiente manera: `use Illuminate\Support\Str;`

Después cambia el code de subir fichero por este:

```
if (!empty($request->file('image_path'))) {
   $newBackdropName = Str::random(20).'.jpg';
   $encodeBackdrop = Image::make($request->file('image_path'))->encode('jpg');
   $uploadBackdrop = Storage::disk('public')->put('/img/'.$newBackdropName, $encodeBackdrop->__toString());
   $image->image_path = $newBackdropName;
}
```

Mira este archivo ruta: config\filesystems.php en la seccion de `disks` asegúrate que este el apartado de `public` así:

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path(),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

el `'root' => public_path()` lo ponemos así que hace referencia a la carpeta publica de Laravel. Así no usamos solo la carpeta de imágenes si no cualquier ruta que este dentro de la carpeta `public`. Solo con eso debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

La forma en la que yo lo haría sería optimizando un poco el formulario, la forma en la que escribo los `name` tendrá sentido en los siguientes pasos. Observa que, existe un campo `hidden` para el ID del usuario.

Primero te recomiendo que, si `Image` es un modelo que tiene los campos `path` y `description`, crees el `form` como te muestro a continuación:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('image.save') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input id="image[user_id]" type="hidden" name="image[user_id]" class="form-control" value!="{{ $user->id }}" required />
    <div class="form-group row">

        <label for="image[path]" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Imagen</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <input id="image[path]" type="file" name="image[path]" class="form-control" required />

            @if($errors->has('image.path'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('image.path')}}</strong>
            </span>
            @endif

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">

        <label for="image[description]" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Descripción</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <textarea id="image[description]" type="text" name="image[description]" class="form-control" required> </textarea>
            @if($errors->has('image.description'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('image.description')}}</strong>
            </span>
            @endif

            <input type="Submit" name="" class="btn btn-primary" value="subir imagen" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ahora en tu controlador, usaremos Validate::make y verificarás si existe errores antes de continuar, si todo está bien, con una sola línea crearás el recurso `Image` y tendrás algo como lo siguiente:

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use App\Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('image.create', compact('user'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //Validación
        $validation =
            Validator::make(
                $request->all(),
                [
                    'image.description' => 'required',
                    'image.path'  => 'required|image'
                ]
            );

        if ($validation->errors()) {
            Image::create($request->image);
            return redirect()->route('image.create')->with([
                'message' => 'La foto ha sido subida correctamente'
            ]);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('image.create')->with([
                'message' => 'Existen errores'
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

En tu modelo `Image`, tendrás que tener un mutador para guardar el recurso de la imagen:

```html
public function setPathAttribute($file)
{
    $this->attributes['path'] =  Storage::put('users/' . Auth::user()->id . '/images', $file);   
}
```

Además, si el disco `images` es tu disco que más utilizas sería buena idea que en tu archivo ENV tuvieras: `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER= images` para evitar usar el método `disk()` cada que usas `Storage`.

El último error que muestra se refiere al método create() que usamos para crear un nuevo registro del modelo Image. En tu modelo podrías poner:

```js
class Image extends Model
{

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

   
    // protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id']; // Te faltaría esta línea
    // protected $fillable = []; 
    // protected $hidden = [];
    // protected $dates = [];
    
}
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, me da error :Undefined variable: user (View: C:\wamp\www\Laravel\Insta\resources\views\image\create.blade.php)
Previous exceptions

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta, fíjate en el método create() de ImageController, ahí tomo el usuario de la clase Auth y se lo paso a la vista por medio de compact. Con eso se quita ese error

Comment: gracias ! he cambiado la ruta a la function de store , no? 
Route::get('/subir-imagen', 'ImageController@create')->name('image.create');
Route::post('/image/save', 'ImageController@store')->name('image.save');

pero ahora da fallo en : Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\wamp\www\Laravel\Insta\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 223

Comment: Edité mi respuesta de nuevo, dentro de Validator::make() usa $request->all(). Y con eso no deberías de tener ese error de nuevo :)

Comment: me sigue dando error, perdona, lo de public function setPathAttribute($file)
, tendria que ponerlo en el controlador tambien? no?

Comment: Cuál error te da? Actualiza tu pregunta con los nuevos errores, añade capturas y tu código, hasta el final de tu pregunta, sin modificar la pregunta original

Cuando un mutador (usando set() or get()) no hay necesidad de duplicar los pasos cuando lo guardas o lo mandas llamar

Comment: gracias por tu gran ayuda, ya lo hice, añadi una captura y un link compartiendo el codigo, gracias :)

Comment: se me habia olvidado por completo modificar el modelo de imagen, he puesto lo nuevo que has añadido, y me da error de : Class 'App\Storage' not found

Comment: Storage no es uno de tus modelos, tienes que importarlo así: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

En el controlador que puse están importadas las clases que necesitabas

Comment: lo pongo y me da : Cannot use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage as Storage because the name is already in use

Comment: he subido todo a un repositorio : https://github.com/luishgc93-cc/insta

Comment: Necesitas quitar el otro use que dice Storage

Comment: lo he quitado y me da error : Class 'App\Storage' not found